# Request going directly to view instead of controller when they have the same name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller

I'm experiencing a weird behavoir when I try to make a view for an MaximumRequestLengthExceeded error page. It seems like when the Controller Action is named the same as the View the request goes directly to the view and I get the following exception:

Unable to cast object of type 'ProjectNamespace.Views.CommonError.MaximumRequestLengthExceeded' to type 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'.

This is when both Action and View are called either "MaxRequestLengthExceeded" or "MaximumRequestLengthExceeded".

If I call the Action one and the view another like follows, it works perfectly fine in both variations.

```
public class CommonErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MaxRequestLengthExceeded()
    {
        return View("MaximumRequestLengthExceeded", null);
    }
}
```

Also I have another Controller "Portal" with an Index action and an Index view, both called the same and they also work perfectly fine. If I move this MaxRequestLengthExceeded action into that controller I also get the error again.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be missing out on?